# Docker: failed to add the pair interfaces (operation not supported)

Tags: linux, debian, docker, debian-jessie, ovh

After installing Docker, I am getting an error when I try to run the Hello World example:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 4145d0fccd96b904e4ab4413735f1129b8765429bad5be71dc8d5f4c0760666d:
failed to create endpoint high_saha on network bridge:
failed to add the host (veth7f6f907) <=> sandbox (veth788d9dc) pair interfaces: operation not supported
```

(I have just upgraded my Debian server from Wheezy to Jessie)

Does anyone has an idea why I get this error? Did I missed something during the upgrade?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've booted your system with OVH's custom kernel, which is built to OVH's specifications, and may not be suitable for running software you want to run.

Change your dedicated server configuration to boot from the kernel installed on the hard drive provided by your Linux distribution.

[image: OVH boot configuration screen]

Comment: I installed a new kernel and told Grub to use it. It now works ! Thanks !

Comment: If should be noted that if you updated to a new kernel but still running on the previous installed version, the this error appear. After rebooting the issues goes away.

Answer (score 231):

In my case, the error appears every time I update my Linux kernel. It disappears when I restart the computer.

I am using Arch Linux

Comment: That is normal, since on a kernel upgrade, all .ko module files in `/usr/lib/modules/{KERNEL_VERSION}` of the running kernel are deleted. Docker needs some tun / tap modules to create the interfaces and trying to load them fails after a kernel upgrade. Rebooting helps because all module files are there for the new kernel. Another work-around would be to re-extract the modules for the old kernel if you still have the pacman package lying around and want to avoid the reboot.

Comment: Did you reboot after kernel update?

Comment: same here. that made the error disappeared and the container to start properly after reboot.

Comment: Also works on Manjaro. Just reboot.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Good ol' Arch...

Comment: Would you know of a way to avoid the reboot automatically? I think I remember seeing a pacman hook somewhere that did it but I can't find it anymore

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27426#issuecomment-278524987) @CLOVIS?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem (pair interfaces: operation not supported) and I use a custom kernel. For me the cause was a missing module "Virtual ethernet pair device" CONFIG_VETH.

> │ CONFIG_VETH:
>   │     │ This device is a local ethernet tunnel. Devices are created in pairs. When one end receives the packet it appears on its pair and vice versa.
>   │ Symbol: VETH [=m]
>   │     │ Type  : tristate
>   │     │ Prompt: Virtual ethernet pair device
>   │     │   Location:
>   │     │     -> Device Drivers
>   │     │       -> Network device support (NETDEVICES [=y])
>   │     │         -> Network core driver support (NET_CORE [=y])

hope it helps

Comment: This solved the issue in the context of building my own kernel. Refer to this for other config options: https://blog.hypriot.com/post/verify-kernel-container-compatibility/