# Can't run docker-container 'failed to create endpoint frosty_varahamihira on network bridge'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, kernel, linux-kernel

When I try to run the hello-world docker image I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint frosty_varahamihira on network bridge: failed to add the host (vethc6c068f) <=> sandbox (veth82a7475) pair interfaces: operation not supported.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I red [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/738773/docker-failed-to-add-the-pair-interfaces-operation-not-supported) post which seems to be the exact same problem but I can't manage to install a different kernel.

I tried the following to install a new kernel, which led me to the next error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb
--2021-10-22 13:47:14--  https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1223448 (1.2M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb’

linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-05070 100%[===================================================================================================>]   1.17M  2.53MB/s    in 0.5s

2021-10-22 13:47:20 (2.53 MB/s) - ‘linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb’ saved [1223448/1223448]

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
dpkg: error processing archive linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive linux-image-unsigned-5.14.9-051409-generic_5.14.9-051409.202109300934_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.7.5-050705-generic_5.7.5-050705.202006220832_amd64.deb
 linux-image-unsigned-5.14.9-051409-generic_5.14.9-051409.202109300934_amd64.deb
```

For that error I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120879/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-linux-image-headers-generic) for example, which did not help.

This might also help

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /boot
total 33299
-rw------- 1 root root  5112454 Sep 29 07:51 System.map-5.13.0-1008-raspi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   241335 Sep 29 07:51 config-5.13.0-1008-raspi
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     2560 Jan  1  1970 firmware
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Oct 13 13:29 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19242515 Oct 13 13:30 initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Oct 13 13:29 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Oct 13 13:29 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-1008-raspi
-rw------- 1 root root  9492544 Sep 29 07:51 vmlinuz-5.13.0-1008-raspi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Oct 13 13:29 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-1008-raspi
```

I am using `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2`. Here other versions:

Docker

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5
```

Ubuntu OS-Version

```
Ubuntu 21.10 aarch64
```

Kernel

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -rn
ubuntu 5.13.0-1008-raspi
```

I am thankful for any hint and idea!

Comment: sorry bro, but you're trying to install an amd64 kernel on an arm64 system. Did your read the error messages ? [ package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64) ]. Also your current kernel is more recent than the one you are trying to install. Is it really what you want to do ?

Comment: please post output of command `grep VETH /boot/config-5.13.0-1008-raspi` and `lsmod|grep veth`

Comment: the virtual ethernet module may not be loaded, that's what I'd like to see. => `sudo lsmod | grep veth` to see if the module is loaded and `sudo modprobe veth` to load it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No that's not what I want and you're, my kernel is quite up to date.
What I want is to solve the error I get when I run a Docker-Container.
The output for ` grep VETH /boot/config-5.13.0-1008-raspi` is `CONFIG_VETH=m`.
For `lsmod|grep veth` I do not get an ouput.

Could you explain to me what I can conclude from that?

Comment: Here the output for `sudo modprobe veth`:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module veth not found in directory /lib/modules/5.13.0-1008-raspi`
For `sudo lsmod | grep veth` I do not get an output.

Comment: This is the issue. `CONFIG_VETH=m` means that you kernel was built with veth support as a module. So you should have in `/lib/modules/5.13.0-1008-raspi/kernel/drivers/net` a file named `veth.ko`. But if `sudo modprobe veth` fails, it means that the file `veth.ko` is not present. Can you post the output of `sudo dpkg -l|grep kernel`

Answer (score 8):

install the linux-modules-extra-raspi package to get the veth module.

Comment: This solved this issue for me, thanks!